# YOLO multiple annotations on same object

Tags: image-processing, annotations, yolo, object-recognition, roboflow

Is it ok to put multiple annotations of the same class on the same object?
Is it going to break or not affect or increase accuracy?

[OneBirdMultipleAnnotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vprY.png)

[Iv put multiple bounding boxes of the same class on an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB7B0.png)

Answer (score 0):

This probably won’t do anything because overlapping boxes are filtered out with Intersection Over Union. You can read more about [how the metrics are calculated](https://blog.roboflow.com/mean-average-precision/) here.

If you’re using a modern YOLO like v5 or v7 you might want to try [labeling with polygons](https://blog.roboflow.com/polygons-object-detection/), though. It does what it looks like you’re trying to do (give the model more information about where the object of interest is compared to the background) and is easy to do with the [Smart Polygon](https://blog.roboflow.com/automated-polygon-labeling-computer-vision/) model if you’re already using Roboflow.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Im using a YOLOV4-tiny, as far as I know it only accepts bounding boxes.